# Tracking testing assignments with Microsoft TFS

Tags: windows, visual-studio, tfs

We use Vs2008/2010 with TFS 2010 for our source control, because it also lets us create custom work item types that we can use for project management, such as product backlog items and sprint backlog items.

One item thats not tracked (by machine) is build regression test tasks for release candidates. Our regression testing is part automated, part manual, and the manual part can take several days. Currently we use an excel spreadsheet with a list of all the test cases, and then the testers just fill in results and notes.

I've been proposing creating a build regression test template that contains each test case, default owner, and then when we want to do regression testing on a build, we can automatically create work items for every test in the template.

My argument is that if the regression test work is mandatory for the project, and the results should be tracked, then writing additional TFS work items make sense, especially since the work items can hold estimates, giving managers an idea of how much re-test time remains.

The argument against this is that we already have high level work items to capture the overall project test requirements, and the regression testing is basically a "re-test", so new work items would be duplicate.

My question: Is anyone else doing anything like this? Is it reasonable to use TFS to track outstanding re-test tasks?

Note: we don't own Visual Studio Test Professional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's reasonable to go with your suggested solution. You should have another work item type for the "test tasks", that can be linked as children to the test requirement work items. Doing that, like you said, would allow you to track results, progress, reporting, etc. You can also add other fields like build number, tested by, tested date, etc. to the work item type for history, something that cannot be done with just one test requirement work item type.

Essentially, what you proposed is done in the ITestResult object in the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.dll.